# How do I check my applicationIconBadgeNumber value?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unnotificationrequest

I want my `redDot` to display when I have some value in badge, i.e `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber` this is the code I wrote, but doesnt seem to work :

```
import UserNotifications

@IBOutlet weak var redDot: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    runCheck()

}

func runCheck(){
    if (UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber>=1) {
        self.redDot.alpha=1
    }
    else {
        self.redDot.alpha=0
    }
}
```

Comment: This is likely not the root cause, but the `>1` should probably be `>=1`

Comment: @snorthway yes it is not, but thanks. I made that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Based on our conversation in chat about this, you have three things you need to happen:

1. You set up a notification to fire later with a badge number. But the notification will not automatically set the badge number.
2. You have to handle the notification when it fires, check the badge number value and update your app's badge number explicitly
3. You check the app badge number in your other view and show/hide the red dot.

I think you are doing #1 & #3 but not #2.

Comment: sorry... how can you just check from a controller if the value of the badge number changed?