# How can I check value of my badge number?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app which send remote local notifications, I want to check value of my badge and display `redDot` accordingly. This is what I tired but doesn't seem to work,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber>=1{
        self.redDot.alpha=1
    }

    else{
        self.redDot.alpha=0
    }
}
```

when I print the value of `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber` it prints `0` instead it of `1` because thats the value of my badge.

Comment: What is the value of `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber` at that point (either use `po` in debugger or a print and look in console)

Comment: @LouFranco its `0`

Comment: What problem are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: @rmaddy it doesnt show my `redDot` because the badge value is being printed as `0`

Comment: Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @rmaddy , no I want my redDot to be shown when I open up my app, because my app still has the badge number but it doesnt, prints the value in `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber` as `0` instead it should be `1`

Comment: Then update your question to reflect that issue. Your question says nothing about the fact that you seem to be getting the wrong value from `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber`.

Comment: BTW - this is a repost of [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42955562/how-do-i-check-my-applicationiconbadgenumber-value) which you accepted an answer for. Why was that answer accepted if you are asking the same question again?

Comment: @rmaddy it does now.

Comment: @rmaddy it didnt, I've unchecked the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You set up a notification to fire later with a badge number. But the notification will not automatically set the badge number.

You have to handle the notification when it fires, check the badge number value and update your app's badge number explicitly.

You check the app badge number in your other view and show/hide the red dot.

Comment: I already have a notification which fires later. and updates my badge number. But how do I update it explicitly ?